# Can Backbone collection url depends on model urlRoot?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can Backbone collection url depends on model urlRoot? For example

```
var _User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/users',
    defaults: {
        email: ''
    }
});

var _Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return this.model.urlRoot;
    },
    model: _User
});
```

Comment: Explain of code - I want to setup url for Model and Collection in one point. Collection must getting url from Model attributes. If I'm wrong - write why please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you want

```
var _User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/users',
    defaults: {
        email: ''
    }
});

var _Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function url() {
      return this.model.prototype.urlRoot;
    },
    model: _User
});
```

Comment: You should explain your code. And better to do the code snippet.